# Convert date to as.Date format in R

Tags: r, as.date

i do understand there are lots of questions asked regarding date formatting in R, but couldn't locate the proper answer to mine at least:

I do have the following date provided:

21-07-'17

The initial idea was to simply utilize the standard one as : "%d-%m-%y" but I do get N/A as system does not recognize the apostrophe in date.
Appreciate the proper as.Date format solution.

Answer (score 2):

`lubridate` has no trouble with this

```
lubridate::dmy("21-07-'17")
#> [1] "2017-07-21"
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```r
as.Date("21-07-'17", format = "%d-%m-'%y")
# [1] "2017-07-21"
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `'` (single-quote) before converting:

```r
as.Date(gsub("'", "", "21-07-17"), format = "%d-%m-%y")
# [1] "2017-07-21"
```